# What does "in the sere and yellow" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, literature

I am currently reading "[A Study in Scarlet](http://www.forgottenbooks.org/info/A_Study_in_Scarlet_1000915804.php)" by Arthur Conan Doyle. On page 33 is a sentence I don't understand:

> Well, if a man can stride four and a-half feet without the smallest effort, he can't be quite in the sere and yellow.

**What does "in the sere and yellow" mean?**

---

Note:
It seems to be related to this part of Macbeth:

> I have liv'd long enough: my way of life
>       Is fall'n into the sear, the yellow leaf;
>       And that which should accompany old age,
>       As honour, love, obedience, troops of friends,
>       I must not look to have; but, in their stead,
>       Curses, not loud but deep, mouth-honour, breath,
>       Which the poor heart would fain deny, and dare not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means he has not yet entered the autumn of his life, and is yet fit and hale.

In a comment below, MetaEd writes:

> *‘Sere* and *yellow* are descriptive of an autumn leaf. Thus “in the sere and yellow” is a metaphor for being near the end of one’s life. In the quoted passage, it is used to mean that he has not yet entered the autumn of his life, and is yet fit and hale.’

Comment: Agreed: the answer only lacks research.

Comment: @ΜετάEd Are you seriously proposing I cite literal dictionary definitions for separate components of an extended metaphor (here, of *sere* and *yellow*)?  Or are you suggesting a scholarly analysis of the combined allusion from the perspective of literature?  Given that dictionary lookups and literary analysis are both off-topic, what else were thinking? Careful now, [we know whither that leads](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5864952#5864952). :)

Comment: Not at all. I am saying "[w]e expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise". Your answer lacks the facts and reasons which support your conclusion. You could write: *‘Sere* and *yellow* are descriptive of an autumn leaf. Thus “in the sere and yellow” is a metaphor for being near the end of one’s life. In the quoted passage, it is used to mean that he has not yet entered the autumn of his life, and is yet fit and hale.’

Answer (score 12):

As in the Macbeth quote, *"in the sere and yellow [leaf]"* is a poetic way of saying **of advanced years, elderly**. I don't know if Shakespeare actually coined it, but he certainly gave it currency.

[Sere (also, sear)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sere) - *dried and withered*, carries much the same significance as *yellow* in this specific metaphoric context. Like autumn leaves, an old person's skin may be yellow and withered.

Here's a typical self-explanatory example - ["...he was in the "sear and yellow leaf" of his life."](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=B62efyszvF8C&pg=PA5&lpg=PA5&dq=%22in%20the%20sear%20and%20yellow%22&source=bl&ots=clhexcMrKD&sig=SXNHCt2l_3L41fExI_1GZ-Q971A&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9p8yUKuQJuiV0QW9vYGwBg&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22in%20the%20sear%20and%20yellow%22&f=false)

Comment: Dried up is the same as yellow?  Don't think so.  It's just that both happen to the leaf as the year fails.

Comment: A mod has deleted my previous comment, but may this one remain on record to indicate that I think the above comment is pointless. I also don't have a high opinion of **five** people who have thus far seen fit to silently downvote this answer.

Comment: Perhaps five people share the opinion of @tchrist and did not feel the need to post "me too" comments.

Comment: @ΜετάEd: Perhaps. I see that comment has just accrued another upvote, so presumably at least 5 people (4 upvotes + tchrist) think *sear* and *yellow* in OP's context mean something significantly different. Having just googled a bit further back in time, I'm now convinced Shakespeare's was the original, primarily evoking autumn leaves. For my money, he did also intend the reference to evoke *old, withered skin*, since the underlying target is *old, decrepit **people***, but that's all Lit. Crit. anyway.

Comment: I agree with you that "sere" and "yellow" both contribute to the age metaphor. I agree with @tchrist taking exception with the statement "sere - dried and withered, carries much the same meaning as yellow". As written, you are plainly saying "sere" and "yellow" both mean dried and withered. Since that's not what you mean, I suggest you reword the sentence.

Comment: @ΜετάEd: I certainly didn't mean to suggest "sere" and "yellow" are  equivalent in a general sense - that's why I specifically said *"the same meaning ... **here**"*. Perhaps "significance" would have been better than "meaning" - I'll try rephrasing along those lines.

Comment: @MetaEd For posting exactly one minute later than tchrist's answer, which was not supported at the time, (and despites the recent edit still isn't) nor explained in any detail, FF's answer was downvoted four times. I would argue that by today's standards, tchrist's answer is still low quality, and this answer is by far superior.

Answer (score 1):

Metaphor for a withered autumn leaf ... here's another one, in the description of the tattered sails of the Ancient Mariner's ship

"The planks look warped! and see those sails,
How thin they are and sere!
I never saw aught like to them,
Unless perchance it were
Brown skeletons of leaves that lag
My forest-brook along"

Answer (score -1):

I agree that both authors are talking about the tag end of life, but it seems to me that A.C. Doyle is harking back to the lines from Macbeth and Shakespeare is using the noun sere, which according to the O.E.D. meant  **bolt.** George Lyman Kittredge in the glossary to his editing of *The Complete Works of Shakespeare* gives this entry "**sere,** a part of a gun-lock between the hammer and the trigger." So it's not just that in old age you are withered and yellowed. There is also little time left.  According to the O.E.D. the adjective sere, used by Coleridge, means **dry or withered.** But Shakespeare was using the noun, not the adjective.